# how to use CUDA to create an array of indices of matches from another array? With atomic?

Tags: cuda, atomic

I have a array in device ,the array is like[0,1,0,0,1...], only have 0,1. I want to create a new array and put the number 1's index in the new array.

I think it should use atomic. I have no idea. How to implement?

Comment: Atomics are not the way to go here. Instead what Thrust (see the answer below) is doing under the hood is a parallel (exclusive) scan to determine the index of each one followed by (or even better fused with) a parallel map (transform).

Comment: You can find multiple implementations of a scan (prefix sum) in the official CUDA samples ([here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/scan) and [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/shfl_scan)). These will probably not perform as good as the library versions, so I would suggest Thrust as below or CUB (i.e. [`cub::DeviceSelect::Flagged`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_select.html) with a counting iterator) which is used in the backend of Thrust for production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using stream-compaction. With Thrust it could look like this

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#include <vector>

struct IsOne{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(int i) const{
        return i == 1;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int> h_array{1,0,1,1,0};
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_array = h_array;

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_indicesOfOnes(d_array.size());
    auto end = thrust::copy_if(
        thrust::device,
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(5),
        d_array.begin(),
        d_indicesOfOnes.begin(),
        IsOne{}
    );
    int numIndices = thrust::distance(d_indicesOfOnes.begin(), end);

    for(int i = 0; i < numIndices; i++){
        std::cout << d_indicesOfOnes[i] << "\n";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0
2
3
```

Answer (score -1):

So you want to find the indices of all the 1s, producing an output array whose length is the count of ones?

Almost certainly better to work in private chunks than to have all threads (whatever you call them in CUDA) serialized by incrementing a shared atomic output position.  That strategy would be disastrously slow, getting no parallelism except when scanning through 0s.  Maybe you had some better idea for how to use `atomic`, but you didn't mention it.

Have each "thread" count 1s in its chunk, then prefix-sum those results across chunks to find the starting point in the output array for each chunk.
Then (after all earlier chunks are done) copy its local array of indices to the right position in the final shared array.

Collecting results between chunks might be done with atomic, but I think you'd want an array of start-positions instead of serializing things with atomic for only 1 chunk start-point at a time.

IDK whether it would be faster to generate a local array of indices during the first pass as you count, or to re-scan the original array to generate indices.  That would let the first pass just be a simple sum (which is the same thing as counting the matches in this case).  If 1s are very rare, writing a temporary array and copying it might be good.  If they're common, keeping the first pass simple and light-weight is probably good, not costing a lot more memory access / cache footprint.

---

The overall problem is somewhat similar to the parallel prefix-sum problem for dependencies between chunks, but it's the starting position that isn't known here, instead of what offset you need to add.

The prefix-sum part of what I'm suggesting is just over chunks, one value per thread, so this step doesn't have to do a lot of work between waiting for earlier chunks and starting up the 2nd phase.

I've never actually used CUDA so I'm not going to attempt code, but this is how you can parallelize the dependencies inherent in this problem in a way that's probably friendly for what GPUs can do.

It would work well on a multi-core CPU where you'd maybe have an array of `atomic<ssize_t>` output counts / positions.  Perhaps starting zero-initialized, and when a thread finishes its chunk it writes a count to the array biased by 1, so it's non-zero.  Or perhaps `chunk_counts[thread] = -(count+1);` so it's definitely non-zero, and negative.  Then it checks if it's the first thread, or if `chunk_counts[thread-1]` is non-zero and *positive* (else `.wait(0)` on it?), and if so writes its `chunk_counts[thread] = chunk_counts[thread-1] + count;`  Actually you wouldn't need to store both the negative local count and the positive prefix-summed count, just one or the other depending on how you collect.

And on a CPU, probably better to have one thread responsible for collecting the results, prefix summing, and notifying all the other threads to wake again.  Instead of serializing with a chain of each thread waiting for a previous thread to write its value.  Perhaps also on a GPU.  That one collector thread can notify workers to start phase 2 as it goes along in the prefix sum.

Comment: thank you! I will learn.